# Как создать ветвление в std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Я хочу создать вот такую [image: необходимая структура]

все хранится в одном векторе, для построения использую несколько струкрур.

```
struct Datas
{
    std::string DataName;
    std::vector<std::string> Data;
    int length;
    std::string Type;
};

struct Topic
{
    std::string TopicName;
    std::vector<Datas> DataList;
    int countData;
};

struct Node
{
    std::string NodeName;
    std::vector<Topic> TopicList;
    int countTopic;
};

struct Group
{
    std::vector<Node> NodeList;
    int countNode;
};
```

но у меня вопрос можно ли реализовать как то иначе и сделать доступ к блокам более простым и быстрым?
Если это имеет значения данные будут заносится из json и могут меняться какие то отдельные данные.

Comment: Ну, судя по тому, что у вас структуры все же разные - хранится это все **не в одном** векторе :) Как вариант, я бы подумал об использовании списков - особенно если данные могут по ходу работы удаляться.

Comment: @Harry, данные удаляться не будут а только меняться, и нет один вектор, просто в итоге я его объявляю так `std::vector<Group> test;`.

Comment: 1) Неясно, зачем вам члены типа `count...`, если вектор имеет `size`. 2) Если нужен доступ к узлу по имени то можно `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> datas;` т.е. использовать map вместо веторов

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "простым и быстрым"? По индексу ображение будет очень даже быстрыми, да и конструкция `test[3].NodeList[2].TopicList[4].Data;` не выглядит такой уж сложной. Хотя чутка инкапсуляции, думаю, не повредило бы

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb а можно как то в этой части `struct Datas
{
 std::string DataName;
 std::vector<> Data;
}; ` у вектора менять тип в зависисмости от записываемого значения, например если пишем в вектор строку то тип string а если целое число то int

Comment: Если перечень типов известен - [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), если нет - [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). Ну это если у вас есть С++17. Если нет, то можно найти аналоги в boost. [Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ab73e8cc571ccd2)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, ну vs2017 поддерживает с++ 17, но при компиляции получаю ошибку `#error: class template variant is only available with C++17`

Comment: Гуглите что-то вроде "visual studio enable c++17"